# Roll back after using sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8") to the default value

Tags: python, utf-8, sys

I made the mistake of using :

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

before realizing that using it, is strongly discouraged (things can break later), and that there are better ways to solve problems related to encoding.

What to do now, and how can I set the value to its default one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove those lines from your project, and re-run. The change only applies to the current Python interpreter.

Otherwise, the Python 2 default is ASCII, you can reset the value with:

```
sys.setdefaultencoding("ascii")
```